# How to use Greasemonkey @include for objects

Tags: javascript, include, greasemonkey

I want to change a site from an object.

For example the address is `http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/SqSlUz-J-jw/default.jpg`
and I want to open a new window if the address includes `http://i4.ytimg.com`.

For web pages you can use `// @include http://i4.ytimg.com*`, but this doesn't work in my case because the target -- `http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/SqSlUz-J-jw/default.jpg` -- is not a website so the script won't run.

Comment: The question is not clear.  What do you mean you "want to open a new window"?  Are you trying to replace the picture, or do you want to show it in a pop-up, or navigate away from the page, or what?

Comment: @Brock Adams: The problem is that greasemonkey dont accept it as s site so every code I want to use will not run.I think Even location.href wouldnt work.

Comment: it is true that the GM-engine will never trigger on that picture load.  That does **not** mean that your **true** goal cannot be accomplished.  But we need to know what that is to show how.  What would you do *if* a GM script could fire specifically for that image?

Comment: It's like to use an other size for the image.Example: I open the image http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2081/3529756333_b311a7eb44_z.jpg but I want the original size so I write a script to change the _z to _o sou you get this link http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2081/3529756333_31e14c30f6_o.jpg Now the script change the adress from normal to the original image. This would happen with location.href = original;

Comment: Rene you can do what you want if you follow my example below, you'll need to either determine how a thumb's url translates to a original's url, or you could use [GM_xmlhttpRequest](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) to determine what the original's url is, somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `// @run-at   document-start` which only [Scriptish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scriptish/) supports atm.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            EXAMPLE
// @namespace       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286896/
// @include         http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/SqSlUz-J-jw/default.jpg
// @run-at          document-start
// ==/UserScript==

GM_openInTab("http://i4.ytimg.com");
```

**Update:** Rene you can do what you want if you follow my example, you'll need to either determine how a thumb's url translates to a original's url though, or you could use [GM_xmlhttpRequest](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) to determine what the original's url is, somehow. If you want help figuring that out then you should ask another question.

Comment: code runs but only by normal links. IF I open "http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/SqSlUz-J-jw/default.jpg" nothing happens.

Comment: Using what version of Scriptish and FF?

Comment: I'm assuming that you used Greasemonkey.. you'll have to use Scriptish to do what you want, because GM will not.